# How can I make old existing google ad tag responsive. is it possible to make the existing one responsive?

Tags: google-dfp

We need to make the old ads responsive to fit in mobile devices, I tried to follow the instruction here to make the google ad tag responsive https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/3423562?hl=en but it seems to work only in desktop application.

My question is, it is possible to make the existing one which is not responsive to responsive or I need to generate new ad tag for responsive.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the style to **style="display:block"**
and add **data-ad-format="auto"**,

Alternatively, you can generate a new responsive ad and change your **data-ad-slot** value with your previous **data-ad-slot** value.

I did the same for my site (www.sipnbet.com) // Check the ad at the bottom of the site

It works FINE :)